# Creating a new column in pandas with respect to the values of other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a sample data as:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
  0.       1.      1.      0
  1.       1.      1.      1
  0.       0.      0.      0
  1.       1.      1.      0
  1.       1.      1.      1
```

I would like to create a new column(output) which shows 1 if all the row values of the dataframe are 1, otherwise 0.

The sample output is shown below:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4. output
  0.       1.      1.      0.     0
  1.       1.      1.      1.     1
  0.       0.      0.      0.     0
  1.       1.      1.      0.     0
  1.       1.      1.      1.     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numpy select()

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np



condition = [(df.column1==1) & (df.column2==1) & (df.column3==1) & (df.column4==1)]
choices = [1]
df['output'] =np.select(condition, choices, default= 0)
```

if you have multiple columns you can use the np.apply_along_axis()

```
def ex(x):
    a = 0
    if x.all() == 1.0:
        a = 1
    return a

df['output'] = np.apply_along_axis(ex,1,df)
```

Comment: I had only focused on the questions asked, thanks for bringing it to my notice. I have edited it accordingly. cheers

Comment: My opinion - `apply_along_axis` is worse solution like first, because loops, whic is necessary avoid in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only `0, 1` values use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), because `0` is processing like `False` and `1` like `True`:

```
df['new'] = df.all(axis=1).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['new'] = np.where(df.all(axis=1), 1, 0)
print (df)
   column1  column2  column3  column4  new
0      0.0      1.0      1.0        0    0
1      1.0      1.0      1.0        1    1
2      0.0      0.0      0.0        0    0
3      1.0      1.0      1.0        0    0
4      1.0      1.0      1.0        1    1
```

If there are also another values compare by `1`:

```
df['new'] = df.eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If need choose only some columns:

```
cols = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']
df['new'] = df[cols].eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```